# How to dispatch api response data into ngrx store from a ngrx effect service

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx, dispatch, effect

I'm struggling to dispatch data to the ngrx store after data is fetched from Api. I actually have a ngrx effect service loginEffect.ts as bellow :

```
constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private store: Store){}

    login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loginAction), 
        switchMap(({request}) => {
            return this.authService.login(request).pipe(
                map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
                    return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) 
               }),
               tap(() => (request.user.username == 'admin') ? this.router.navigate(['dashboard']) : this.router.navigate(['login']) ),
        catchError(() => {
            return of(loginFailureAction())
        })
            )
        })

    ))
```

It calls the loginService.ts that perfom the api call and login operation like bellow:

```
export class loginService {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient, private store: Store){}
  
    login(data: LoginRequestInterface): Observable<CurrrentUserInterface>{
      const url = environment.apiUrl + '/users/login'
      const Option ={ headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*', 
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'USER_CODE': data.user.USER_CODE})
      };
      return this.http
      .post<authResponseInterface>(url, { username: data.user.username, password: data.user.password }, Option)
      .pipe(map((response: authResponseInterface) => response.user))
    }
}
```

The login is successfull and user is redirected well. But I need to grab the token, userId and user_code from the response yielded by the api, and then dispatch them into the ngrx store in order to use them as params for other api call. But I'm hitting the wall of dispatching such data to the ngrx store. I was good at redux with React app, but not with ngrx. So How can I dispatch the response to ngrx store from the loginEffect.ts or from the loginService.ts?
I thought that dispatching it inside the loginEffect.ts is a better bet and so I called the

> this.store.dispatch(loginSuccessAction({currentUser}))

this but it caused visual studio editor to error out as shown on screenshot:
[image]

In the loginAction.ts I have loginSuccessAction like this:

```
export const loginSuccessAction = createAction(
    actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCES,
    props<{currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface}>()
)
```

I even think to write an action to excecute on(loginSuccessAction, ...) in the reducer.ts, but I can't do that because the values that I have to dispatch are only available in the loginEffect.ts or from the loginService.ts. I will be very greatfull for your hepl. Thanks in advance.

**EDITED ACCORDING TO** @MikeOne's **CONTRIBUTION**

When trying to reduce the payload to reducers.ts I did this:

```
on(loginSuccessAction, 
    (state: AuthStateInterface): AuthStateInterface => ({
    ...state,
    USER_CODE:'admin',
    token: 'xrdxgfchgb',
    userId : 63,
}))
```

And redux devtool displays the exact data I reduced in there, but those data aren't real data from api, as you can see they are manually set. So my struggle is about how to set the currentUser data fetched from the api response in the reducer. This is the loginSuccessAction that implements the currentUser interface:

```
export const loginSuccessAction = createAction(
    actionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCES,
    props<{currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface}>()
)
```

And this is how logingEffect was supposed to map the api response to currentUser:

```
@Injectable()
export  class loginEffect {

    constructor(private actions$: Actions, private authService: AuthService, private router: Router, private store: Store){}

    login$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(loginAction), 
        switchMap(({request}) => {
            console.log(request); return this.authService.login(request).pipe(
                map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
                    console.log(currentUser);  return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) 
               }),
               tap(() => (request.user.username == 'admin') ? this.router.navigate(['dashboard']) : this.router.navigate(['login']) ),
        catchError(() => {
            return of(loginFailureAction())
        })
            )
        })

    ))

    
}
```

As you can see, I console.log the currentUser in the

```
map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
                        console.log(currentUser);  return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) 
                   })
```

But it gives **undefined** in console. Is my "request" properly mapped to currentUser inside the loginEffect.ts ? If so how can I then pass it in reducer.ts . Thank you so much.

Comment: The action is already dispatched from your effect though..?  loginSuccessAction({currentUser}). So currentUser can be reduced into your store. What else do you need..?

Comment: Thanks @MikeOne yeah I did "return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) " to dispatch but the data was not shown in redux devtool so I thought i was not dispatched properly, since i didn't write explicitly the this.store.dispatch(loginSuccessAction({currentUser})). So since the action is dispatched with the "return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) ", how can I check it result, or troubleshoot to find what blocked it from the redux devtool ?

Comment: In devtools you should see the action being dispatched for loginSuccessAction. If not, it’s hard to tell the reason for it. Are you sure your http call is successful? Put a console.log just before the return inside the effect map to check this.

Comment: Also, check your actions. Are you sure your succes action has a different action name (compared to your loginAction)? Those bugs can really screw things up 

Comment: Yeah @MikeOne, Login Success is shown inside the redux devtools, but not the api's response data that I mapped into currentUser in order to use it.

Comment: The actual data you might not see (maybe in the payload tab?) - until you reduce it in the store.

Comment: Ok, I seem to be missing that essential point. How can I reduce the loginSuccessAction ?

Comment: You haven’t got any reducers yet..? It’s hard to tell exactly without seeing how you modeled your state but it’s pretty straightforward and more details can be found on the ngrx site..?

Comment: @MikeOne I edited the question according to the insight you gave yesterday. I found the way to reduce the currentUser, but I just don't know how to replace the manual data I put in the reducer with the payload data from api. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your reducer should use the prop from your action i.e currentUser like below

```
on(loginSuccessAction, 
    (state: AuthStateInterface, {currentUser}): AuthStateInterface => ({
    ...state,
    USER_CODE:currentUser.user.username,
    token: <token>,
    userId : <id>,
}))
```

Comment: Thanks @Mak15 . I passed the props as you suggest but the Redus devetool only yields initialStata i.e the vaules inside : const initialState: AuthStateInterface = {
    isSubmitting: false,
    USER_CODE: '',
    token: '',
    userId : 0,
    roleId: 0
}

Comment: Even though the project compiles successfully I think that something is wrong with {currentUser}. How can I test that object {currentUser} inside the loginEffect.ts and see whether it contains the payload or not ?

Comment: can you put debugger in browser on this step and check what it coming?

Comment: you can put a breakpoint on this step in inspect -> sources -> <reducer.ts>

Comment: I already debugged 'currentUser' inside loginEffect as follow in map((currentUser: CurrrentUserInterface) => {
                        console.log(currentUser);  return loginSuccessAction({currentUser}) 
                   }) and it says currentUser : undefined on browser.

Comment: can you put a log in the map of login service, where you get response.user?

Comment: It was pretty much about mismatched data types with interfaces. Your answer combined with that of @MikeOne 's comments helped me figure it out. Thanks